# NWJS ('child_process').exec command not found

Tags: javascript, process, exec, node-webkit

Hello every one i am making my first node webkit app and everything went okay. Until i wanted to "release" it. My app uses a child process to run a command on the command line but i installed the module that i needed to run with npm install -g so it only works for me. To try and fix this i installed it again without -g but i still get command not found. How can i reference to it?

code :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

child = exec('peerflix "'+q+'" --vlc',function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The command not found problem is due to the app's PATH aren't equal to system PATH. So the process.env.PATH doesn't contain node env: '/usr/local/bin'.
There's one way that I've figured out is to reset the process.env.PATH with node env location.

Before using exec, set process.env.PATH like this:

```js
var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);

if (!isWin) {
  process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':/usr/local/bin';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i spent an hour to try and fix it and it got it! Here is how for anyone who needs it

the peerflix command uses a file called app.js and all i had to do was run that with nwjs so the working command looks like this:

```
'./nwjs.app/contents/macos/nwjs ./source/node_modules/peerflix/app.js "'+q+'" --vlc'
```